# FuelPHP call to undefined method

Tags: php, unit-testing, fuelphp

When I run `php oil test` on Mac
under FuelPHP framework, I get an error:

```
Error - Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Util_Filesystem::fileExistsInIncludePath() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 205
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe your xampp version has not the same phpunit version that fuelphp uses!?

Comment: No, it has the same verison. And it works fine on my peers laptop

Comment: Does the class file exist?